# Adding two array collection in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we add two array collection in SQL, or Is there any alternative to 'MULTISET UNION'?

```
DECLARE @aDropdownList nvarchar(Max) = 'a,b,c'  
DECLARE @anotherDropdownList nvarchar(max) = 'x,y,z'
DECLARE @LOC nvarchar(max) = NULL 
SELECT @LOC = @aDropdownList MULTISET UNION ALL @anotherDropdownList
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have arrays. What are you asking here? What are your expected results? What is `@aDropdownList` meant to represent, a single value, with the value `'a,b,c'` or the **three distinct** values `'a'`,`'b'` and `'c'`? If the latter, then why are you using a scalar variable? A Scalar variable represents a **single** value, not many. You should be using a table variable with 3 rows inserted into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with newer version of SQL Server then you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` :

```
SELECT value AS DropDownItem
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@aDropdownList, ',') adrop
UNION ALL
SELECT value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@anotherDropdownList, ',') androp;
```

If you don't have a newer version, then you would have a user defined table valued function that split your drop-down items.